# woocommerce rest api python get products

Tags: python, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

What I need is to get all product `IDs` that are `'instock'` using python.
It looks like this:

```
wcapi.get('products', params={"per_page": 100, 'stock_status': 'instock', 'tag': '1111'}).json()
```

This code works, but have `max limit 100 per_page`, I don't understand how can I acquire rest of them (about 2k items in stock) and moreover this request returns all info about products, but I need only `IDs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#list-all-products), I see that you can pass a **page** parameter also.

That makes it pretty straightforward to iterate all pages:

```
page = 0
While True:
  products = wcapi.get('products', params={'per_page': 100, 'stock_status': 'instock', 'tag': '1111', 'page': page}).json()
  # retrieve ids from **products**
  if len(products) == 0: # no more products
    break
  page = page + 1
```

Edit: Bear in mind that this is going to process **per page** (in this case 100) products per loop.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach because I have a large quantity of products and kept getting disconnected with a while loop.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_product_ids(start, stop):
    my_list = []
    for page in range(start, stop):
        response = wcapi.get("products", params={"per_page": 1, "page": page}).json()[0]
        print(f"Page: {page}", end='\r')
        my_list.append(response['id'])
        df = pd.DataFrame({"Product_ids": my_list})
        df.to_csv(f'WooCommerce_product_ids_{stop}.csv', index=False)

get_product_ids(start=22001, stop=23001)
```

Answer (score -2):

There can be several approaches for solving this problem
You can fetch all products in a single call or in multiple calls according to your use-case

for example, you want to fetch 2k records in a single call

```
products = wcapi.get('products', params={'per_page': 2000, 'stock_status': 'instock', 'tag': '1111', 'page': page}).json()
```

But the above approach is not good enough as the number of products may vary from time to time, therefore limiting products to be fetched is not a good solution for the long run.

Hence the better solution is to fetch the product details by multiple calls

```
page = 1 #The first page number to loop is page 1 
products = []
while True:
    prods = wcapi.get('products', params={'per_page': 100, 'stock_status': 'instock', 'tag': '1111', 'page': page}).json()
    page += 1
    if not prods:
        break
    products.append(prods)
```

After fetching all the product list you can fetch the product_ids like

```
product_ids = [product['id'] for product in products]
```

Comment: First solution doesn't work, `per_page` is limited to 100 :-/